Getting a rule on the left side of text that skips the first line of the environment using mdframed
I'm trying to get a definition environment where there's a rule on the left side of the text, except for the first line. I currently have the MWE below using mdframed, but I don't know how to skip the first line of the rule and not have any indent on that line. I'm open to similar solutions with an alternative to mdframed, but would like to keep the amsthm functionalities. Thanks for any help!

from
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Rule on the left environment
\newmdenv[
topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false,
skipabove=0pt, skipbelow=0pt,
leftmargin=0pt, innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt
]{leftrule}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{def_internal}{Definition}

\newenvironment{defin}[1][]{
    \begin{def_internal}[{#1}]
        \begin{leftrule}
        }{%%
        \end{leftrule}
    \end{def_internal}
}   

\begin{document}
    This is my definition
    \begin{defin}
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{defin}
    but I'm hoping for something formatted automatically like
    \begin{def_internal}
        Here's the first line of my definition that I forced this length
        \begin{leftrule}
            and here's the rest! \lipsum[66]
        \end{leftrule}
    \end{def_internal}
\end{document}


Hi @George, I am a bit confused, what would you actually want where you have put 'Here's the first line of my definition...' And why can't you just put it as the first line of your definition. Sorry if I'm missing something.

The problem here is that I had to manually separate the first line out so that the rule starts on the second line, where I hoped to get LaTeX to automatically exclude the first line from the rule on the left

With ntheorem and tcolorbox:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremindent10pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcolorboxenvironment{defin}{% 
  blanker, breakable, 
  before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt, 
  overlay={\draw ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-11pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=1pt]frame.south west);},
  overlay first={\draw ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-11pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=1pt]frame.south west);},
  overlay middle and last={\draw ([xshift=1pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=1pt]frame.south west);},
  }


\begin{document}
    This is my definition \lipsum[1]
    \begin{defin}
        A definition not broken across pages.
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{defin}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{defin}
        A definition broken across pages.
        \lipsum[70]
    \end{defin}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}


Detail:


Just adding an answer that combines CarLaTeX's answer using tcolorbox with this answer that helped me define a new theorem style with similar indentation using amsthm:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    
    
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{indented_def} % name
{\topsep}                    % Space above
{\topsep}                    % Space below
{\addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{10pt}
    \addtolength{\linewidth}{-10pt}
    \parshape 1 10pt \linewidth}                  % Body font
{-10pt}                           % Indent amount
{\bfseries}                   % Theorem head font
{.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
{.3em}                       % Space after theorem head
{}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{indented_def}
\newtheorem{def_internal}{Definition}

\newenvironment{defin}[1][]{
        \begin{def_internal}[{#1}]
            \begingroup
            \parindent = 15pt
    }{%
            \endgroup
        \end{def_internal}
    }


\tcolorboxenvironment{def_internal}{% 
    blanker, breakable, 
    before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt, 
    overlay={\draw ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-11pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=1pt]frame.south west);},
    overlay first={\draw ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-11pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=1pt]frame.south west);},
    overlay middle and last={\draw ([xshift=1pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=1pt]frame.south west);},
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[66]
    \begin{defin}[New def which resets indentation]
        \lipsum[66]
        
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{defin}
    \lipsum[66]
    \begin{def_internal}[Internal def (paragraphs don't indent)]
        \lipsum[66]
        
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{def_internal}
\end{document}


